# No sound from the rear/woofer speaker of Asus Zephyrus G14 2023

Tags: alsa, asus, pipewire

On Asus Zephyrus G14 2023, sound only comes out of the pair of tweeter speaker. The woofer speaker does not produce any sound at all on either on Analog Stereo, Analog Surround 4.0, or 2.1 configurations. Using Ubuntu 23.04